# log4net AdoNetAppender not working in Application_Start()

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, log4net

Have an asp.net, dot net 4 web app, using log4net for logging.  We log to the windows event log and an Oracle 11g table.  We can log to the oracle table everywhere except in Application_Start.  The really annoying thing?  It fails silently.  Turn on console logging, and redirect to a file, and the last entry before we start logging is "Added appender named [AdoNetAppender] to logger [root]."  Repository.Configured (for log4net-default-repository) is true for all loggers at this point. Reversing the order in which the appenders apear in the config file has no effect.

**The log4net part of the config file:**

```
<log4net debug="true"> <!-- log4net.Internal.Debug set to true in appSettings, System.Diagnostics.Trace is output to file.>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
        <param name="LogName" value="AppLog" />
        <param name="ApplicationName" value="AppName" />
        <!-- Only log warnings and errors. Levels are ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF -->
        <threshold value="INFO" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%property{log4net:HostName}] %-5level WEBUI[%logger] [%u]  %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="Logging.CustomAdoNetAppender, Logging">  <!-- So it can find the custom appender-->          
        <ConnectionStringName value="Database"/>
        <connectionType value="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />            
        <bufferSize value="1"/><!--This is the number of log entries, not the size in bytes... "1" sets to no buffering -->
        <commandText value="audit_tracking.Add_log" />
        <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />            
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_Thread" />                
            <dbType value="AnsiString" /> <!--AnsiString is VarChar.  "String" will assume NVarChar -->
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%thread"></conversionPattern> 
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_Log_Level" />
            <dbType value="AnsiString" />
            <size value="225" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_Logger" />
            <dbType value="AnsiString" />
            <size value="225" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_Message" />
            <dbType value="AnsiString" />
            <size value="4000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_Exception_Str" />
            <dbType value="AnsiString" />
            <size value="4000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%exception"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_Server_Name" />
            <dbType value="AnsiString" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_User_Name" />
            <dbType value="AnsiString" />
            <size value="255" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%property{UserName}"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="I_User_Id" />
            <dbType value="Int64" />                
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%property{UserId}"/>
            </layout>
        </parameter>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />            
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />  
    </root>
</log4net>
```

**The C# parts:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    read_init_data();//reads some init data from the db and caches it <-- this works, btw.

        //log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();//not needed since we config in AssemblyInfo.cs
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserName"] = "";//HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name does not exist yet
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserId"] = "0";//so we can't get a user id, either...
        log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Global");

        logger.Info("Application Start");//logs to event log but not to db...        

    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    ulong UserId=GetUserId(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);//db call to get user id. 

        //log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();//not needed since we config in AssemblyInfo.cs
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserName"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserId"] = UserId;
        log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Global");

        logger.Info("Session_Start");//logs to event log and db    

}

public class CustomAdoNetAppender : AdoNetAppender
    {
        public string ConnectionStringName
        {
            set { ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[value].ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does read_init_data do any logging?

Comment: No.  Turned out to be two things.  One was log4net being unable to find the appender, the other was a db trigger that I was assured wasn't there, but which was there.  So when the first one was fixed, the db problem was still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on break on all exceptions in visual studio to see if there is an exception thrown within log4net which it catches and swallows but might tell you the reason.

That's helped me in the past when it's not been logging to a database because of a login error with the database user.

Comment: Did that.  No exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a dba if there are any constraints or triggers that might fire when you feed in an empty string, and they assure you there aren't, and there seems no other reasonable explanation, ask them again, while standing in their cube.  Make them show you.

Just got an email informing me that the constraint they assured me didn't exist does, in fact, exist...

Why no exception is thrown I still don't know.

Comment: I'm not surprised that log4net didn't give you an exception (see "Is log4net a reliable logging system?" on this page: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html. In future you can try this http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging.html to see what is going on...

Comment: Well, Oracle should complain...  And there was an exception (well, error message) complaining that it couldn't find the appender until I added the assembly name to the appender name in the config file.

Really, two problems, the db problem, and the assembly name problem.  Fixing the second fixed the actual logger problem.  But the db problem obscured that...